# jquery - how to get iframe contents after a post

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am trying to submit to an iframe and get back the response.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipens/4qRAV/)

For test purposes, test.php just returns 'abcd'.
I want to capture this response - for testing, just alert it out.

Firebug doesn't even enter this:

```
$d('#imageform').submit(function(){
```

Can anybody see what I have missed - ie why the submit isn't being called?
Many thanks for any help!

Comment: you're binding to a submit event inside a click event... that makes no sense for what you're trying to do. Please include all relevant code directly in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to listen to the click or even the submit event. Just listen to the iframe's load event.

```
var $d = jQuery.noConflict();
$d(function ($) {
    $('#imageupload').load(function () {
        console.log($("#imageupload").contents());
    });
});
```

don't forget to also change the type attribute on your submit button to submit.